# I use an Azerty keyboard. How can I handle keybindings easily?

Tags: keyboard

As a Belgian, I use a non-qwerty keyboard with AZERTY (A/Q switched, W/Z switched, M/; switched, changed layout of symbols near alt gr). This is rather annoying, especially on games like Oblivion, Fallout or Morrowind (forces QWERTY), The Wolf Among Us (uses the letters instead of the keys for keybinding, which gets VERY annoying since it's quicktime heavy) and games which don't allow to rebind keys (which is surprisingly many of them these days).

I have a dual monitor setup, which means I often am passively listening to Youtube or something while playing some games. I'm looking for a solution for games which don't allow key rebinding and use the letters, but which does not involve setting my entire computer to qwerty and where I can set it for individual games (because the games with rebindable keys don't have this issue).

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is simply buying a qwerty keyboard. Use it for games that you are having this problem with and use your current one for typing.

Comment: Complain to the producers and demand bindable keys, IMO a PC game that doesn't allow rebinding keys is not worth the struggle of trying to play it with a different keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Alt + Shift" keyboard shortcut is your friend.

It does "set your entire computer to qwerty". But it's easy and quick enough to swap between "azerty" and "qwerty" that it shouldn't bother you much.

But if you have to write ingame ... Then I know no other option than rebinding, and if you can't, you're stuck.

Comment: Interesting; I know the "Win + space" shortcut, but I didn't know the "Alt + Shift" one. You might want to mention that the shortcut actually cycles through configured input methods, so if AZERTY is the only input method defined the shortcut won't work. In my case, I have QWERTZ (SG), Pinyin (Chinese), IME (Japanese), so the shortcut cycles through all 3 of them, but doesn't ever change into QWERTY (US).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought "Alt + Shift" was really common knowledge.
You're right about cycling, but I know for a fact (I'm using an azerty) that if you kept the default config and have an "azerty" keyboard, it will switch between the "qwerty" and "azerty" keyboard layout.

Comment: I see. I'm not really willing to remove my Chinese or Japanese layouts to verify your claim, so I'll just trust your words. Regardless, this answer does provide an interesting solution, so I'm giving you a +1.

Comment: since win 10, or maybe win 7, you can set this cycling to work for the window where you press it, meaning your game will be in QWERTY and anything else will still be in AZERTY

Answer (score -3):

If you are using a Windows computer the answer is rather simple: Behold the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboardlayouts.aspx) - Free.

If the doesn't work you could use Microsoft hot scripts to code a program that will run in the sys tray yourself. I think you could probably find a port for Linux too.

Hot scripts is easy and you can copy and paste scripts until you are comfortable to write your own. They are very easy to write and you can learn about them here - http://ahkscript.org/ .